# Accessing Scala pair

Tags: scala

Consider the following function definition:

```
def foo(l: List[(Char, Int)])
```

The following expression is valid

```
l.map(t => t._2 + t._1)
```

Is there a way to access the elements of the pair by name?
I have tried the following, but it does not compile:

```
l.map((c: Char, x: Int) => c + x)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to unpack a tuple with *round brackets*, you'll need *curly* ones (which apply a partial function):

```
l.map { case (c, x) => c + x }
```

In the future, with [Dotty](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty), you should be able to unpack it as follows:

```
l.map((c, x) => c + x)
```

Comment: Do you have a link for that Scala 2.12 feature? :)

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz I mixed it up with the Dotty :\. [Slides can be found here](http://www.slideshare.net/Odersky/scala-days-nyc-2016), see slide 37.

Comment: Maybe also show a destructuring without using case?  `l.map { tuple => val (c, x) = tuple; c + x }`.  Can avoid potential MatchErrors if the case makes the function only partially defined.

Comment: @hayden.sikh Wouldn't you prefer to use `collect` instead? i.e. `l.collect { case (c, x) => c + x }` and avoid the MatchError.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz that feature is not in Scala 2.12

Comment: @HongxuChen It was my fault, I misguided him with my previous edit of the answer.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov collect will avoid the MatchError of the input pattern cannot be matched, but will instead silently discard the collection's contents at runtime. Having the explicit destructuring forces it to be a compile time check. All of these forms have their place, just with their own tradeoffs, and ur might be worth listing them, if you agree.

Comment: @hayden.sikh It's all tradeoffs, I definitely agree. But since this is a `List[(Char, Int)]`, when do you suppose such a `MatchError` like that can actually occur?